# Object of class Illuminate\Mail\Message could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5 trying to send email but getting error

> Object of class Illuminate\Mail\Message could not be converted to string

here is my controller

```
public function contactreply($contact, Request $request){
    $reply = new Reply;
    $reply->subject = $request->subject;
    $reply->message = $request->message;
    $reply->email = $contact;
    $reply->save();
    $mail = Mail::to($contact)->send(new ContactReply($reply));
    return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Email Sent Success');
}
```

here is my ContactReply.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ContactReply extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $reply;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($reply)
    {
       $this->reply = $reply; //dd($reply) passing all value here
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('admin.contact.reply')
                    ->subject($this->reply->subject)
                     ->with([
                        'message' => $this->reply->message,
                    ]);
    }
}
```

my view file

```
<div>
  {!! Markdown::parse($message) !!}<!-- Using Markdown Package -->
</div>
```

I think I missing something because i did same on my old project and that is working fine.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 42):

i don't know why its a bug of laravel but $message is blacklisted for mail on view

when i tried `{{ $message }}` getting error and not sending the message
when i change $message to any name like `{{ $content }}` its working fine
yeah its working fine now thanks for contribute all

Comment: This was a problem for me as well. Could you find this anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: Found it and made an answer out of it!

Comment: Thanks @sid, Yes, there is a problem with {{ $message }} in laravel 5.7 version. I have changed the variable name to other one and tried. It worked for me. Thanks again. Saved my life :)

Comment: very informative answer this solve my problem I was facing for the last 2 hours

Answer (score 17):

```
$message variable is not available in markdown messages.
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#writing-mailables

I think this is because the $message represents the Illuminate\Mail\Mailable instance itself.

Comment: This was the problem for me, thanx!!

Answer (score 2):

Change the message input name in your contact controller

$input = $request->all();

```
    Contact::create($input);


     \Mail::send('contact.contactMail', array(
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'phone' => $input['phone'],
        'subject' => $input['subject'],
        'message' => $input['message'], // change in this line
```

to this -->

$input = $request->all();

```
    Contact::create($input);


     \Mail::send('contact.contactMail', array(
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'phone' => $input['phone'],
        'subject' => $input['subject'],
        'form_message' => $input['message'], //after change it will work
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `laravel-log-dumper` to dump any value and send it to log with the function `ld()`.

Installation:

```bash
composer require spatie/laravel-log-dumper
```

Usage (according to your example):

```php
$sentMail = \Mail::send('contact.contactMail', array(
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'phone' => $input['phone'],
        'subject' => $input['subject'],
        'form_message' => $input['message'],
        ...
    )
);

ld($sentMail);
```

More info about `laravel-log-dumper`:
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-log-dumper